# HAXM installation problem - system requirements are not satisfied

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I'm trying to install HAXM so I can get Android Studio to work but I always get the same error "The system requirements are not satisfied"

[image: HAXM settup]

This is the report I get after trying to install it, it only says that VMX is not enabled. So I went into BIOS and enabled these two settings.
[image: BIOS]

After that when I run HAXM installer I get same error but diferent report.

[image: HAXM report 2]

Now it looks like VMX and EPT are not suported, and Hyper-V is enabled but it is disabled in Windows Features. I tryed looking thru other threds but I cound find anything. My procesor is i5-5300U and on Intel site it  says everything is supported.
[image: Prosecor settings]

Comment: What's the output of `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`? Run it in a command prompt with admin rights.

Comment: I got `The operation completed successfully.`

Comment: Try to reboot now and run haxm installer.

Comment: Still got the same error and same report, as in the second picture.

Comment: You disabled hyper-v, but haxm installer thinks it's enabled. The question is how it checks if hyper-v is enabled. Ask your question at https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ***hp*** device, then you can restart your PC and while its booting, repeatedly press the **esc** key until a startup menu appears.

- Press F10
- Navigate to **system configuration**
- Select **Virtualization Technology**
- press **enter**
- Select **Enabled** and press enter
- Press **F10** key and select **yes** to save

It Worked For Me

Comment: definitely this was the solution for me,

Answer (score -1):

solved for me

1. Download HAXM by this link: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases
2. ENABLE VT technology in BIOS
3. Disable Hyper-V in the "Window features" (entire category)
4. Reboot your PC.

If above steps don't work try next:

1. https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/388#issuecomment-860783921
2. https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/385#issuecomment-907947835

Don't forget reboot system after the each step.